# Was the Queen's English as we know it artificially created?

Tags: pronunciation

There is a theory that American English is in fact a great deal closer in terms of pronunciation to the language Shakespeare spoke than the official British version, a.k.a. the Queen's English.

Proponents of this theory maintain that British aristocracy invented its own "high tone" pronunciation in order to distance themselves from the lower classes - sometime in the 19th Century (i.e. during Queen Victoria's reign), and that Cockney is a failed attempt to imitate said aristocracy.

I couldn't find any essays or monographs that deal with this issue directly. Allusions can be found here and there, in numerous articles.

Is this true?

Comment: I've heard that theory, but I thought it was generally restricted to the speech of the people from the Appalachians.

Comment: Basically, vowel shift. As an aside, not so long ago some places in Yorkshire (I'm) we're still theeing and thouing

Comment: Languages and dialects evolve; I don't think you can say that one way of speaking is more 'natural' or 'better' than another. If you read Dickens you find that Cockney speech was different in the 19th century.

Comment: Isn't all language artificial? Or are you thinking in terms of something like [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto), which was invented entirely from scratch? What do you mean by *artificial*?

Comment: I don’t think anyone is seriously claiming that the upper classes _invented_ their own sociolect. More likely, they recognised traits which were associated with dialects and sociolects related to the working-class, and they chose to actively avoid those traits in their own speech and dissociate themselves from them, thus enhancing the difference between the two and eventually creating a true dichotomy.

Comment: "Cockney is a failed attempt to imitate said aristocracy.". I have seldom heard anything as ridiculous as this.

Comment: "If you read Dickens you find that Cockney speech was different in the 19th century. " some allege that he made up the v - w Sam Weller thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh dear. I’d missed that bit in the question. That does indeed sound rather silly. I suppose the practice of rhyming slang so prevalent in Cockney may in part have evolved from mockery of a perceived tendency in the aristocracy towards tabooism (i.e., considering many words taboo and avoiding them in favour of silly euphemisms – a lady sweats not but _blushes_, etc.), but the accent itself is certainly very unlikely to have evolved as an attempt to imitate a lect that is about as far from it as possible.

Comment: "A lady sweats not but blushes" - my mother, nearly a Cockney (Old Kent Road family), told me that "horses sweat, men perspire, ladies glow".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Some ladies glow more profusely than others.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: In what sense exactly is Cockney a "lect that is about as far from [the Queen's English] as possible"? Maybe in social terms, but linguistically, both are fairly closely associated with the speech used in London, which I'd imagine makes them have some shared linguistic features. I don't know about within England, but at least I think they're both more similar to each other than to a Scottish accent.

Comment: @sumelic I mean as far from each other as you could get within that area, not in the entire Anglosphere. Cockney is in almost all respects further from 19th-century upper-class poshspeak than other accents and dialects in south(east) of England, so it is rather a bizarre suggestion that it should have arisen as an attempt on the speakers of them to imitate it. Sort of like saying that the Southern drawl in the US arose from Bostoners imitating a New York accent.

Comment: There are at least three different questions here.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few issues here that should be separated for the purposes of clarity.

#### Shakespeare's English

First — whether what we think of as the "Queen's English" is identical (or nearly so) to Shakespeare's English. There is a general consensus that it is not. People disagree about the details, but David Crystal is an example of a linguist that has spent a lot of time trying to figure out differences between modern pronunciation and Shakespeare's pronunciation.

Pronunciation and grammar have a lot of different parts. Although there is a widespread idea, referenced in the comments, that the grammar or pronunciation used by Shakespeare "survives" in the form of some present-day accent (often alleged to be Appalachian English), this isn't actually accurate. The most that can be said is that *some* features of Shakespeare's English that are not shared with most present-day accents of modern English might be shared with certain dialects of Appalachian English. But the presence of some shared features is in no way a guarantee of total identity between two accents.

#### The "Queen's English"

Second — what "The Queen's English" means, and where it comes from.

"The Queen's English" is a fairly abstract concept that is defined by how it is socially perceived. For simplicity's sake, it can be treated as an entity (a variety of English). But like many linguistic entities, it is not homogenous and its boundaries are not distinct.

The "Queen's English" has been distinguished from other accents by various features, some of which have changed over time. For example, it appears to have once been common to pronounce *often* the same, or nearly the same, as *orphan,* but it is now usual to maintain a distinction.

I don't know of any systematic feature of the "Queen's English", past or present, that was clearly invented abruptly out of nothing.

The closest thing to an "invented" feature of the "Queen's English" that I can think of is that I've seen some literature that alleges that the use of the sound /h/ in present-day standard English is substantially because of spelling pronunciation. Unfortunately, I forget where I read that: you can find a less extreme summary in *[Historical Phonology of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=TAOrBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by Donka Minkova (2014), which only goes so far as to say that "orthographic standardization, especially through printing after the end of the 1470s, was an important factor shaping the later fate of ME /h-/" (p. 107). In any case, while the use of /h/ has historically been a notable social marker in England, I hardly think it could be said to be a unique characteristic of the "Queen's English", and even if its use in southern English accents is largely based on spelling, the sound [h] was not invented as a completely new pronunciation of the letter H—rather, it seems to have been transmitted intact in at least some native vocabulary in other accents of English.

To return to the *often/orphan* example, I have never seen any evidence that the "orphan" pronunciation of *often* was established by someone who was consciously trying to create a new way of speaking. Instead, that pronunciation of *often* seems to have developed as part of a sound change that also affected other words with similar structure. Sound changes usually develop gradually and unconsciously. So I don't think it's really possible to identify the motivation behind the spread (and later decline) of this pronunciation.

It doesn't seem too implausible that some sound changes might have been influenced by pressure to have distinct ways of speaking for distinct social classes. But it seems very imprecise to use the word "invention" to describe that kind of process of unconscious differentiation between accents.

The idea that accents with low overt prestige (such as Cockney) originate from failed attempts to imitate accents with high overt prestige (such as the "Queen's English") is a generally discredited view in linguistics.

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting.